# Common class range for different attributes in same polygon shapefile using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, classification

I have a polygon shapefile which has population attributes pop90,pop91 and so on for 10 years. They have different minimum and maximum value for each of the years. Now I need to do classification for each attribute (pop90, pop91) but with the same number of classes and the range for each class should be same.

Same number of classes is fine but how can I use the same class range for each of the attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a layer file (*.lyr) with the symbology ranges that you want, then when you add a new file, import the symbology from this layer file to classify the other file using a common range.  Also, see the many other Related Q&As on the side bar to this post.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this problem is to choose a reference attribute (for example pop91) and to add new field for attributes which have inadequate number of classes. And for values in a new field you must do interpolation or extrapolation.